# Routing IP to LXC virtual machine

Tags: 12.04, lxc

I use LXC on my Ubuntu server hosted in Hetzner.
The server IP is 5.x.x.85 and the additional IP I bought is 5.x.x.93.

The LXC VM is running on 10.0.3.2.

How to route the additional IP (5.x.x.93) to the VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative way was found in the blog post: http://www.jotschi.de/?p=755